# Trapezoid method for system

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

For $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, we consider the system

$$x'(t)+\alpha x(t)=-\beta y(t), t \geq 0, \\ y'(t)+\alpha y(t)=\beta x(t), t \geq 0, \\ x(0)=1 \\ y(0)=2.\\$$

I want to state the trapezoid method for this problem. Also I want to show that the computation of the approximation vector requires the solution of a linear system. And I want to find the matrix of this system.

The trapezoid method is the following, right?

$$y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2} [f(x_n, y_n)+f(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})]$$

But how can we state the trapezoid method for the given problem?

Also, the rpoblem can be also written in the followng form, right?

$$\binom{x'(t)}{y'(t)}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\alpha & -\beta\\ 
\beta & -\alpha
\end{pmatrix} \binom{x(t)}{y(t)}$$

So this is the wanted linear system that we have to solve, to compute the approximation vector and the matrix of the system is the following, right?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-\alpha & -\beta\\ 
\beta & -\alpha
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Your ode is $z' = Az$ with $A$ being your matrix. The trapezoid method gives $z_{n+1} = z_n + \frac{h}{2}(Az_n + A z_{n+1})$ which you can solve for $z_{n+1}$ (you will have to invert a matrix to get it on explicit form).

Comment: It would help if you rewrote the method (which is indeed the correct one) in variables $(t,v)$ instead of $(x,y)$, where then $v(t)=\pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)}$, the same for their discretizations.

Answer (score 1):

with $z_k = (x_k, \ y_k)'$ and $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\alpha  & -\beta  \\
 \beta  & -\alpha  \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and following the Winter indications we have

$$
z_{k+1} = z_k +\frac h2(A z_k+A z_{k+1})
$$

or

$$
z_{k+1} = \left(I_2-\frac h2\right)^{-1} \left(I_2+\frac h2 A\right)z_k
$$

or

$$
z_{k+1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{4 \alpha  h+8}{\left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right) h^2+4 \alpha  h+4}-1 & -\frac{4 \beta  h}{\left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right) h^2+4
   \alpha  h+4} \\
 \frac{4 \beta  h}{\left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right) h^2+4 \alpha  h+4} & \frac{4 \alpha  h+8}{\left(\alpha ^2+\beta ^2\right) h^2+4 \alpha 
   h+4}-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)z_k
$$